# Apply Sitecore validation to a template during certain workflow actions

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

A simplified description of the problem:

I have a News template and an Events template, each with a unique set of fields.  Both go through a publishing workflow I've created.  There are several actions that can take place with either a news item, or an events item.

1. An administrator can create a new item of either type, and publish it through to the site.
2. A content author can create a new item of either type, then submit it for approval.
3. An item which has been submitted for approval can be looked over by an administrator, then published to the site.

Either in step 1, or step 3, when the "Publish" action occurs, I'd like to validate different fields depending on which item type is being published.  Is there a way to bind validation rules to fields in a template during a workflow action by using the UI, or will this require custom coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Field item has a number of fields for where and how validation should be required and validation errors should be displayed:

1. Quick Action Bar
2. Validate Button
3. Validator Bar
4. Workflow

If you want a given validation rule to run during the workflow approval process, you can set that validation rule in the **Workflow** field for each Field item under each template.  And that's the key - I don't think you want to run these checks during the **Publish** action, I think you want to run these checks during the **Approval** action.

This is all done in the Sitecore Content Editor.  No custom code is required.

Comment: I'd take this a step further and say that the validation should occur earlier, at the draft stage before the item can even be submitted for approval. Why would you want an item submitted for approval when you already know it will have to be rejected because it will definitely fail workflow due to the next step.

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed the steps below to get this working:

1.  Expand the News template in the Sitecore UI to where I can see the list of fields.
2.  Open each field, setting the rule I need in the Workflow field.
3.  Expand the Events template in the Sitecore UI to where I can see the list of fields.
4.  Open each field, setting the rule I need in the Workflow field.
5.  Open the workflow in the Sitecore UI, then add an action there to enforce the workflow.

I agree with the comments, but our customer requested it like this.